# How to remove all the characters on a line before a specified character

Tags: notepad++

I am trying to figure out how to rip all the TLD's from a huge list of domain names. Rather than copy paste each one i'd just like to remove ALL the text before the '.'

Before:

- exmample1.com
- exmample1.org
- exmample1.fr
- exmample1.eu
- exmample1.es
- exmample1.net

After:

- com
- org
- fr
- eu
- es
- net

I have tried all the other methods in all the other questions. None of them work for me.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In "Search and Replace" dialogue box (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)

Under "Search Mode", Choose "**Regular Expression**"

Under "Find What: ", paste

`^.+[.]`

Click "Replace All"

---

**Explanation of PCRE**

^ Beginning of the string

. Any character

+ One or more the previous character (greedy)

[.] One character of dot